# How do I get my icon to horizontally line up with my drop down box?

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

having a bit of trouble lining up my icon with my dropdown box. I'm using jQuery Mobile. I have tried using the inline-block feature but I'm having no luck with it.

Could anyone help me with a solution. Thanks

```html
<head>
<!--jQuery CDN Hosted Files-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body >
<div style="padding: 20px;">

<img src="https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-HhNoCFJ803s/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/ABtNlbAXJpr-jDsvmXVw0tx4PHId84zrlw/mo/photo.jpg?sz=32" class="loginBoxImg">
  <select name="type" id="type">
      <img src="">
      <option value="">Account Type...</option>
      <option value="Teacher">Teacher</option>
      <option value="School">School</option>
  </select><br>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: I have, in the past, given the container an inline-block display and floated the dropdown menu right, but it didn't work.

I have also given the image the inline-block display with the dropdown floated right, still didn't work.

Comment: JQM has grids for this job. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53271194/4845566

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use flexbox to achieve this, first wrap the `select` and the `img` in a container

```
<head>
<!--jQuery CDN Hosted Files-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body >
<div style="padding: 20px;" class="container">

<img src="https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-HhNoCFJ803s/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/ABtNlbAXJpr-jDsvmXVw0tx4PHId84zrlw/mo/photo.jpg?sz=32" class="loginBoxImg">

  <select name="type" id="type" style="min-width:90%;">
      <option value="">Account Type...</option>
      <option value="Teacher">Teacher</option>
      <option value="School">School</option>
  </select><br>
</div>
</body>
```

And then give that container a `display: flex;`

```
.container{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
```

And for the last you need to give to the class `.ui-select` a 90% width

```
.ui-select{
  width: 90%;
}
```

[Here](https://codepen.io/federicomartin/pen/wQegjv) you have a codepen to test it, and [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) information about flexbox and how to use it, let me know if that help!

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I am looking to line them up horizontally, and this is vertically. So essentially I am looking for the image to be on the left hand side of the dropdown.

Comment: Ok, I got it, sorry, check this instead https://codepen.io/federicomartin/pen/wQegjv